# Nautilus scripts in Thunar right-click menu?

Tags: nautilus

Is it possible to insert an entry to Nautilus scripts in the Thunar right-click menu?

I know that Thunar has it's custom actions, but I've got dozens of Nautilus scripts and I really want to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Thunar's custom actions **is** a way to have the same actions in Thunar: by  adding a new custom action with the path to the executable script.

```
sh -c `path/to/script %f`
```

For example, I have a script for downloading subtitles that was made for Nautilus. As I already have Nautilus running that script, to show it in Thunar actions I have added a custom action called "List all subtitles" with the command `sh -c "~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/OpenSubtitlesDownload.py %f"`.

[image]

It is the very same script that can be used from both file managers, only the name is different.

[image]

[image]

The scripts can be saved and run from anywhere in this way, not necessarily in the path required by Nautilus; just set the correct path in Thunar actions.

Answer (score 0):

I place them in "~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts" folder and they show up on right click. You have to tinker a bit to see the differences from menu launching and terminal launching. This is in the Gnome desktop on SIDEBIAN. The directory for nemo is "~/gnome2/nemo-scripts"

Comment: Well, problem is I have no Nautilus or Nemo installed, only Thunar